# Writing values from .csv file to .xml using PowerShell. My script isn't working - critique my code

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I'm trying to automate editing of an xml file using a Powershell script. The script needs to use a .csv file as a data source. The .csv has two columns. A has the original values, B has the replacement values.

Because there are duplicates in the .xml file, I only want to replace values between a particular element, in this case the name element.

I tried writing this script (see code) but the replacement process doesn't work. I don't receive an error message when running the script, but when I open the .xml file after executing it, none of the target values have been changed to the values shown in the .csv file.

The expected behaviour would be that any values contained in the name element will have been changed to the values listed under column B in the .csv file.

```
# Load the csv file
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sourcelabels.csv"

# Load the xml file
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path "C:\labelfile.xml")

# Loop through each row in the csv file
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  # Find the elements in the xml file that match the value in column A
  $elements = $xml.SelectNodes("//element[propertyA='$($row.'Column A')']")

  # Replace the value in the <name> element with the value in column B
  foreach ($element in $elements) {
    $element.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText = $row.'Column B'
  }
}

# Save the updated xml file
$xml.Save("C:\labelfile.xml")
```

Comment: Please update your question to explain _in what way_ it isn't working, and ideally provide sample input and describe the desired output.

Comment: See: [mcve] for more info

Answer (score 1):

If your **labelfile.xml** looks anything like this:

```
<labels>
    <label>
        <element propertyA="changeMe">
            <name>oldValue</name>
        </element>
    </label>
    <label>
        <element propertyA="DoNotChange">
            <name>KeepMyName</name>
        </element>
    <label>
    </label>
        <element propertyA="changeThisOneToo">
            <name>UpdateThisName</name>
        </element>
    </label>
</labels>
```

and your **sourcelabels.csv** file looks like

```
"Column A","Column B"
"changeMe","NewValue"
"changeThisOneToo","This Name Has Been Updated"
```

Then below should work:

```powershell
# Load the csv file
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sourcelabels.csv"

# Load the xml file (this way will use the correct encoding of the file)
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xml.Load("C:\labelfile.xml")
# get a collection of element nodes
$elementNodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//element")

# Loop through each row in the csv file
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    # Find the elements in the xml file whose propertyA attribute match the value in column A
    $elementNodes | Where-Object { $_.propertyA -eq $row.'Column A' } | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Name = $row.'Column B'
    }
}

# Save the updated xml file
$xml.Save("C:\labelfile.xml")
```